# How do I test whether a file on Windows is deletable from PHP?

Tags: php, windows, permissions

I've forgotten how Windows file permissions work!

I'm writing a PHP script that needs to test whether a file is deletable. On *NIX-like systems, it's just a case of testing whether the directory the file is within is writable by the current process. However, how do I test whether a file on a Windows server is deletable?

Comment: To my knowledge, [`fileperms`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) should work. PHP will emulate a *nix environment and result in similar results.

Comment: @Brad: no - NTFS uses ACLs which do not map to fileperms.

Comment: @Brad see my comment on RobB's answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [fileperms()](https://www.php.net/fileperms) to read what the current permissions are.  You can then use [chmod()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to modify the permissions if they do not meet your criteria.

Comment: You can't directly test whether a file is deletable using `fileperms()`. This will tell you whether a file is readable/deletable/executable as well as the type, but file write permissions =/= delete permissions (at least on *NIX). At least on *nix systems, the directory is treated like a file that contains an index of the files within. (vi any directory and you'll see what I mean.) So to delete a file on *nix the system has to delete the entry within the directory file, meaning you need write permissions for the directory (which doesn't propagate). I can't remember how it works on Windows.

Comment: Perhaps you could offer some more details with what exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I thought the question was rather unambiguous; I'm trying to test whether a file is deletable.

Comment: While you question does specify that you are wanting to check if a file can be deleted, it does not specify the handling past that point.  As symcbean indicated, you can use the is_writeable() to check if a file can be written and if it can then it should be able to be deleted unless something is misconfigured for some odd reason.

Answer (score 1):

It should just be a case of checking that both the directory and file are writeable and that the file is not locked.

Unfortunately there's no way I'm aware of to check for existence of locks without a blocking call.

If you know there's no locks on the file, AND testing is_writeable(dirname($file)) && is_writeable($file) returns true AND you still can't delete the file - then I'd be interested to know why - what are the ACLs?

Comment: I'll test this out, try to break it, and come back either way!

Comment: It appears to require modify permissions on the containing folder, but not for the IUSR account, but for the generic Users account. If this is the case, there appears to be no way to test this from PHP. `fileperms()` doesn't take into account modify permissions, or handle the ACL model very well at all. My `is_deletable` function was only designed for better error detection, but the code could deduce that if the file exists and `unlink` fails, modify permissions are not available, negating the need for an `is_deletable` function.